# NSNotificationCenter - same observers with different name

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Is it possible to have one method linked with different names in NSNotificationCenter?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(Finish:) name:@"FinishDownload_data1" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(Finish:) name:@"FinishDownload_data2" object:nil];
```

... etc

In my code, when I call notification, I pass its name and some other params in userInfo Dictionary.

The reason I want this, is because I have run-time generated events. They have same body, but differ only in save target, depending on _data#. I want every download to be handled on the same place.

Problem is, if I use this, notification is not called.

Comment: You could also use the same notification name (`FinishDownload`) in the two cases, but pass a different `object` or `userInfo` when you broadcast the actual notification. Usage of `userInfo` would be preferred, as `object` is usually there to indicate the sender of the notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've posted will work for multiple notification names. You can tell between the two in your callback:

```
- (void)Finish:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"FinishDownload_data1"]) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

There's no reason the notification would not be called. Are you sure you implemented the callback, though?

Comment: Thanks.. with notification.name its ok. I have incorrect userInfo and it caused notification not being called at all.